# Increase the frame rate during cutscenes of Assassin's Creed Brotherhood?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

I have an NVIDIA 9500 GT which has 1 GB DDR2 RAM. While the actual gameplay is quite satisfactory, my frame rate is dropping terribly during cut scenes, which is making the video out-of-sync with the audio.

I've tried lowering some settings and even switched to a lower resolution, but still the frame rate is not getting better!

Comment: This is a classic problem in games, and especially with streaming textures (where you see higher-res textures pop in gradually). The cutscenes differ from normal gameplay in that they move the camera around a lot and the typical delayed loading (of texture data etc) algorithms are not tweaked for this. If there is some way to force or adjust precaching for this game you MIGHT see an improvement. In any event streaming from the HD is a performance bottleneck so the advice in that respect which ketura gave is still applicable.

Answer (score 2):

If it's only happening during cutscenes, I'd be willing to bet the bottleneck is in streaming HD video from your hard drive.  Check and see if there's an option to load SD instead of HD video, and if not your only option might be to install on a faster hdd (I would recommend a WD Caviar Black or any other 7500 RPM drive).  You might also make sure that nothing else is running that makes heavy use of the hdd--e.g. seeding torrents, video recording, disk defragmentation, virus scanning, the list goes on.

Comment: No, Assassin's creed does not have pre-rendered cutscenes...the cutscenes in this game are rendered on the fly! I know this because the choppiness of the cutscenes is directly proportional to the amount of detail...a cutscene indoors is quite smooth while the ones which have more environmental detail are choppy

Comment: Interesting.  I've never heard of a game playing smoother with dynamic content then with previously determined content.  Guess it comes down to either sloppy programming or some sort of rendering issue with the card.  Sorry I couldn't help.